# fieldset not work in page that in MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, fieldset

is Fieldset not Work in default.aspx that use MasterPage ?

```
  <fieldset style="border-style:double">
    <legend>Livraison</legend>
    qsdf
    </fieldset>
```

it not show the border.

Comment: it's like any other HTML control, will work normally, unless you have a nested css rule that overrides the default view. 
consider to use debugging tools like FireBug or Developer Toolbar to see what are the styles inherited from it's parent(s).

Comment: Thanks you..right...i think it is because i use DevExpress

Comment: you welcome, I will post my comment as a suggested answer, consider marking it as answer to avoid any wrong additions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's like any other HTML control, will work normally, unless you have a nested css rule that overrides the default view. consider to use debugging tools like FireBug or Developer Toolbar to see what are the styles inherited from it's parent(s).